# how to get countries list alphabetically arranged with the correct names

Tags: java, countries

I am trying to find all of the name of countries.
I tried to get them from `java.util.Locale` but I found that there is some countries with wrong names and the list is not alphabetically arranged.

to get the list from `java.util.Locale` I used this code

```
private List<String> countriesList = new ArrayList<String>();

public List<String> getCountriesList() {

        String[] locales = Locale.getISOCountries();

        for (String countryCode : locales) {

            Locale obj = new Locale("", countryCode);
            countriesList.add(obj.getDisplayCountry(Locale.FRENCH));

        }
    return countriesList;
}
```

So is there a way to make them alphabetically arranged with the correct names ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Just use Collections.sort(listName) and your list will get sorted

```
List<String> countriesList = new ArrayList<String>();



        String[] locales = Locale.getISOCountries();

        for (String countryCode : locales) {

            Locale obj = new Locale("", countryCode);
            countriesList.add(obj.getDisplayCountry(Locale.FRENCH));
            Collections.sort(countriesList);
            }
        for(String s:countriesList)
        {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
```

> In your code just add sort method before the return statement of the method

```
 private List<String> countriesList = new ArrayList<String>();

 public List<String> getCountriesList() {

    String[] locales = Locale.getISOCountries();

    for (String countryCode : locales) {

        Locale obj = new Locale("", countryCode);
        countriesList.add(obj.getDisplayCountry(Locale.FRENCH));

    }
Collections.sort(countriesList);
return countriesList;
}
```

Comment: thank you !  your solution is working fine, and for the wrong names I changed `Locale.FRENCH` to `Locale.ENGLISH`

Comment: @Spartan Thank You, My pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two separate issues:

1. **The list is not alphabetically arranged.**

You just need to sort the array. There are numerous ways how to do it, one of them could be as follows:

```
Collections.sort(countriesList, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String str1, String Str2)
    {
        return  str1.compareTo(str2);
    }
});
```

2. **Some countries with wrong names**

If there are countries with wrong names, particularly in your language, it will be hard to do anything with it within Java. If you cannot rely on the internal Java country names, you could either put the name list directly into your application "manually", which could be annoying or e.g. use a web service. There are many, check e.g. this [one](http://www.geonames.org/export/JSON-webservices.html#citiesJSON). The advantage of this approach is that the list may be updated if some new countries appears, what happens time to time.